# Отсчет от 1ого, а не от 0

Tags: html, jquery

Есть вот такой код хтмл

```
       <div class="im"></div>
       <div class="im"></div>
       <div class="im"></div>
```

Мне же нужно, в каждый вставить цифру от 1 до 3х

Я пробую вот так

```
    var dv = $('.im');
    for(var i = 1;i <= dv.length; i++){
        dv.eq(i).text(i)
    }
```

Заполняет только 2й и 3й со значениями 1 и 2,  а первый див пустой остается
Все правильно, ибо eq() отсчет начинает с 0, а если я поставлю

```
var dv = $('.im');
    for(var i = 0;i <= dv.length; i++){
        dv.eq(i).text(i)
    }
```

Тогда у меня выведет значения
0
1
2

Пробовал еще так

```
dv.each(function(id){
    $(this).text(id);
})
```

Так тоже выводит
0
1
2

Потому что отсчтет начинается с 0..

Как сделать, что бы выводило 
1
2
3
?

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  counter-reset: i 0;
}

.im:after {
  counter-increment: i;
  content: counter(i);
}
```

```html
<div class="im"></div>
<div class="im"></div>
<div class="im"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
var dv = $('.im');
    for(var i = 0;i <= dv.length; i++){
        dv.eq(i).text(i+1)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуй так

```
var dv = $('.im');
    for(var i = 0;i <= dv.length; i++){
        dv.eq(i).text(i+1)
    }
```

или

```
dv.each(function(id){
    $(this).text(id+1);
})
```